# Why I cannot disable Cookie in asp.net mvc with login.RememberMe = false in method of FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an asp.net mvc project and I activate authentication with the method of `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()`. I don't wanna set cookie and for this then I have written the method in the format of below:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName, login.RememberMe = false);
```

but still I have cookie. How can I remove cookie?

Comment: You are calling a method called `SetAuthCookie`, how do you expect it *not* to create a cookie? How would authentication be done without the cookie?

Comment: It is not possible to authenticate a user without setting a cookie???

Comment: How are you going to know whether that user actually authenticated *after* the login?